# Configsource path using wrongly

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm trying to use a config file by directing there from `App.config`.
I have created a folder named `Config` inside my solution and created a new config file named `Environment.config`.

My `App.Config` looks as following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" /></startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings configSource="Config/Environment.config"/>
</configuration>
```

and the `Environment.config` looks as the following:

```xml
  <appSettings>
    <add key="URL" value="http://foo.aspx"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I'm getting an error which says:

> Result Message:
>   OneTimeSetUp: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Configuration system failed to initialize
>   ----> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : The configSource attribute must be a relative physical path, so the '/' character is not allowed. (D:\tfs\QA - Automation\Projects\ReportAppeal\ReportAppeal\bin\Debug\ReportAppeal.dll.config line 22)

I have tried to switch from "/" to "\" but got a different error.

> Result Message:
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Unable to open configSource file 'Config\Environment.config'. (D:\tfs\QA - Automation\Projects\ReportAppeal\ReportAppeal\bin\Debug\ReportAppeal.dll.config line 22)
>   TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'll probably need to change the way I'm directing the `Environment.config` file but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says:

> The configSource attribute must be a relative physical path

So you will need to change your key to a physical path, not a relative one:

```
<appSettings configSource="C:\Config\Environment.config"/>
```

Or just leave it under the root:

```
<appSettings configSource="Environment.config"/>
```

Comment: What happens when you write a complete path?

Comment: The exact same error:  "The configSource attribute must be a relative physical path". And I set it to be: configSource="D:\tfs\QA - Automation\Projects\ReportAppeal\ReportAppeal\Config\Environment.config

Comment: Ok, I found that in order to use a physical path I need to change the 'configSource' to 'file'. But still wondering about the relative path. It would be important for me when using TeamCity etc..

Comment: Yaniv kapara neshama The source has to be physical because it's like an entry point for the IIS. It needs a specified physical path to know where to start your site from.